# Python Apache Beam failed to retrieve information from BigQuery table due to "This app is blocked"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam

```
import apache_beam as beam

with beam.Pipeline() as p:

    table_spec = 'clouddataflow-readonly:samples.weather_stations'

    (p | beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=table_spec))
```

I tried to run the script above to get information from bigquery table, it prompt me to login using my google account and to give access to "apitools".

[image]

But failed and show this.

[image]

Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you run gcloud auth login https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login?

Comment: It return me 'auth_success'. It works well for 'Google Cloud SDK' but not 'apitools'.

Answer (score 1):

End up you should set your environment variable for "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" with the service account that downloaded from GCP. So it won't prompt you to sign in with any other google account. Then it works.